# Call rest URL from separate layer?

Tags: wcf

I am able to call the rest url if I add the *.svc file in the same project.
If I put the *.svc in the separate project and if I call the url it is not working.

Comment: Improve your question. This doesn't say to much about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The svc file is just an entry point so ASP.NET can route requests to your service correctly in IIS. Make sure the svc file is in the project hosted in IIS. It does not make sense at all to distribute that file in other projects.